# Is it possible to integrate AD account with asp.net Identity/OWIN in MVC5?

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I am new to MVC application and will implement an intranet web application. I plan to use AD accounts to authenticate users(Windows Authentication) and integrate with asp.net Identity to manage application Roles and authorize application users with Roles(Not all users with valid AD account is the application users).

Is it possible to integrate asp.net Identity with AD account? How to build/access the asp.net Identity database?

Answer (score 0):

I think the fact that some of your users would not have valid AD accounts would probably be the indicator that AD could not ultimately authenticate all the users.  I have been using Windows Authentication and for our Intranet sites we have enabled ADFS but we are still basically still using AD.  We have not tried ASP.net Identity. I have never heard of a "Mixed Mode" scenario for AD and Asp.net Identity.  I would love to hear if someone knows better.